# Why do I get varying variable importance charts when I run code?

Tags: r, survival, random-forest

Dataset found [here](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Heart+failure+clinical+records).

Why is it that once I run R-Markdown, I get a different variable importance chart on my survival model?

```r
library(randomForestSRC)
library(survival)

ucifile <- "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00519/heart_failure_clinical_records_dataset.csv"

HF <- read.csv(ucifile, header=TRUE) 

HF$anaemia = as.factor(HF$anaemia)
HF$diabetes = factor(HF$diabetes, levels=c(0, 1), 
                     labels=c("Absent", "Present"))
HF$hypertension = factor(HF$high_blood_pressure, 
                         levels=c(0, 1), labels=c("Absent", "Present"))

HF$sex = factor(HF$sex, levels=c(0, 1), labels=c("Female", "Male"))
HF$smoking = factor(HF$smoking, levels=c(0, 1), labels=c("No", "Yes"))
HF$DEATH_EVENT = as.factor(HF$DEATH_EVENT)

HF <- select(HF, -high_blood_pressure)

set.seed(0)

fit <- rfsrc(Surv(time, DEATH_EVENT) ~ .,
             data = HF, 
             ntree = 1000, 
             importance = TRUE,
             nsplit = 5)

#fit
plot(fit)
```

**I'd like to only get the chart with *ONE* event-- the first.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: You code illustrates a single fitting of a random forest, so you get one result from that. When you say you get different results, are these from running the same code twice?

Comment: @RichardHardy It is! First is inside RStudio/Posit and the second is in the RMarkdown file.